# Oleum is used to prepare sulfuric acid. Why do H2O+SO3 not give H2SO4?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I encountered the fact that $\ce{SO_3}$'s solubility in water is low but even when $\ce{H2S2O7}$ (oleum) is added to water it is $\ce{SO3}$ only that react with water . Please explain the process.

Comment: What process? The Contact process?

Comment: Solubility of $\ce{SO3}$ in water is not low at all; in fact, they react quite vigorously.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between these equations for the Contact process?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/32264/7951)

Comment: Also see [this](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34138/preparation-of-sulfuric-acid-through-contact-process) and [this](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47588/where-does-the-sulfuric-acid-used-in-contact-process-for-manufacturing-sulfuric/47632#comment78961_47632)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reaction $\ce{SO_3}$ and $\ce{H_2O}$ is exothermic, which means it releases a lot of heat.The heat produced will boil $\ce{H_2SO_4}$ and become $\ce{H_2SO_4}$ gas. The $\ce{H_2SO_4}$ gas is hard to condense causing this method to be unefficient.

Comment: It would boil water before reaction would end